# Why does the stack view depend entirely on the variable "n" to be rendered?

Tags: golfscript

One in golscript can view the stack easily by pressing enter in the shell. But there is a default variable that changing it to a value that does not contain "\n" removes this behavior. Why is this happening?
Example of the behavior:

```py
> 1
[1]
> 2 3 4
[1 2 3 4]
>
[1 2 3 4]
> "As we noted the stack can be displayed by each enter button";
[1 2 3 4]
> :n
> 1
>
> 918882 182391 13829213
> "Now the stack can no longer be displayed.";
>
```

The stack is worth "\n" as we see with this:

```py
> n print
"\n"
[]
> "\nDaniel \n":n;
[]
Daniel
> "Daniel":n;
>
```